# Warning when casting int to HWND

Tags: c++, windows, casting, hwnd

I have a program I'm writing for Win64 in C++ that is executed from a parent program, and needs to set its parent window to the parent program's window. The parent program passes in it's `HWND` in as a command line argument, and I'm parsing the argument as an `int` (using `stoi()`) before it is cast to an `HWND`. A simplified version of my code is shown below:

```
int parentHwnd = stoi(args[HWND_INDEX]);
SetParent(childHwnd, (HWND) parentHwnd);
```

However, I'm getting the following error when compiling:

```
warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'HWND' of greater size
```

Is there safe way to cast an `int` to a `HWND`and eliminate this error? Or should I be parsing the given command line arg to something other than an `int` that will safely be able to be cast to a `HWND`?

Comment: [According to this,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384203.aspx) the `HWND` should be sign-extended.  Not sure off the top of my head how best to go about doing that, hopefully one of the C++ experts will chime in.

Comment: You should also read [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)  Key quote: "Yes, it is technically legal.  It is also technically legal to juggle chainsaws."

Comment: `(HWND)IntToPtr(parentHwnd)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When passing pointers/handles you should use [std::stoull](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoull/?kw=stoull);
2. And use explicit cast `HWND parentHwnd = (HWND)std::stoull(args[HWND_INDEX]);`

Comment: Not sure I understand how signed/not-signed is applicable here.

Comment: D'oh!  Must be half-asleep today; I was right the first time.  You're interpreting the argument as an unsigned 64-bit value, and that's not going to work reliably if the parent is 32-bit, because the effect is to zero-extend the handle when you [should be sign-extending it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384203.aspx).  Passing it as a signed value rather than an unsigned one will always work.